# mysql: modify output in a way that some specific records appear twice with a different parameter

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a following output from sql query:

```
parent_id id     status
1         NULL   before
2         19     before
2         20     after
```

MySQL:

```
select 
 parent_id_B,
 id,
 IF(created_final_at >= @start_date, 'after', IF(created_final_at < @start_date AND created_final_at >= @back_end_date, 'before', IF(created_final_at IS NULL,NULL,'late'))) as status_inv
from bblabla
```

I need following:
if id is NULL and status is before, I want to add a record with the same id and parent id but with status 'after'.

```
parent_id id     status
1         NULL   before
2         19     before
2         20     after
1         NULL   after
```

I want to use the upper query as a subquery, without creating any new tables. After I want to perform a grouping by the parent_id (counting ids) and after by status (averaging counts). So, it means I need the same structure as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` your query with another 2-row-query. It will generate 2 rows when your condition (in `on`) is fulfilled, otherwise it will use the original values (once). It will maintain your original structure and use your query as a subquery.

```
select parent_id, id, coalesce(new_status, status) as status
from ( <your query> ) as subquery 
left join 
  (select 'before' as new_status
   union select 'after') as rowdoubler
on id is null and status = 'before';
```

It will not check if the row already exists in your resultset (you can maybe add `distinct` then, depending on your data).